# How to setup debugger in Eclipse Juno for C/C++ on windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse Juno for C/C++ Developers.

I created a small sample project with a few .c and .h files and a makefile. The project seems to compile fine and creates an executable. I'm then able to run the executable within Eclipse and in windows.

The problem is if I try debugging. I get the following error message:
[image: eclipse debug error]

Here's my debug configuration:
[image]

Comment: Have you entered the correct path to your binary in "main" tab of launch configuration? Are you able to run that binary?

Comment: The setting in "main" tab is exactly the same as for  "run" configuration. "Tun" works, and "debug" doesn't work. So the problem must be in the "debug" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select a parser for the debugger to function.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_parser.htm

Comment: Right-clicking on project and selecting settings, I was able to get to the parser settings. That fixes the problem. Thanks!!!